# How could I create a single page website (with 2 separate pages), if my divs are positioned using percentages?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scalability, responsive

I'm new to web design, and am trying to make a single page website with 2 pages. When I place the code for the second page (in a div) underneath the first, it doesn't give me two web pages one under the other, but places all the img's etc of the second page over the first. I was wondering whether this has to do with me using percentages in the CSS. If so, what would you suggest me to do? The problem is, I was recommended to use percentages in order to develop a fluid layout (this hasn't worked out yet; I still have to figure this all out completely). Is there a way to fix the problem, and keep using percentages?

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MySite</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body class="cateringpage">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="leavesimg">
                <img src="leaves1.svg" alt="leaves" class="bananaleaves"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="cateringbannerimg">
                <img src="cateringbanner.svg" alt="catering" class="catbanner"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="cateringputolblueimg">
                <a href="cateringmenu.html">
                <img src="cateringputolblue.svg" alt="cateringputo" class="catputo1" onmouseover="this.src='cateringputodblue.svg';" onmouseout="this.src='cateringputolblue.svg';" ></img>
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>

<div id="pge2" class="cateringmenupage">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="greenboardflat1img">
                <img src="greenboardflat1.png" alt="greenboard" class="greenboardflat1"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="cateringmenubannerimg">
                <img src="cateringmenubanner.svg" alt="cateringbanner" class="cateringmenubanner"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="printiconwhiteimg">
                <a href="DOMINIKSTEXT.pdf">
                <img src="printiconwhite.svg" alt="print" class="piwhite" onmouseover="this.src='printiconred.svg';" onmouseout="this.src='printiconwhite.svg';" /></img>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="bbcatlputoimg">
                <a href="index.html">
                <img src="bbcatlputo.svg" alt="backtomainmenu" class="bbcatlputo" onmouseover="this.src='bbcatdputo.svg';" onmouseout="this.src='bbcatlputo.svg';" /></img>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mmcat">
                <p>home page</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS FILE:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body.cateringpage {
    background-image: url("woodbackground.png");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body.cateringmenupage {
    background-image: url("woodbackground.png");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.leavesimg {
    position:absolute;
    width: 95.3%;
    height: 89.6%;
    left: 2.5%;
    bottom: 5%;
}

img.bananaleaves {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.cateringbannerimg {
    position:absolute;
    width: 43%;
    height: auto;
    left: 27.5%;
    bottom: 26%;
}

img.catbanner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.cateringputolblueimg {
    position:absolute;
    left: 16.25%;
    width: 14.5%;
    left: 42%;
    bottom: 13%;
}

img.catputo1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.haloboximg {
    position:absolute;
    width: 29%;
    height: auto;
    right: 11%;
    bottom: 11%;
}

img.hbox {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.greenboardflatimg {
    position:absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    left: 5%;
    bottom: 2%;
}

img.gboard {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.dailylunchbannerimg {
    position:absolute;
    top: 15%;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    left: 7.5%;

}

img.dlbanner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.dailylunchtxt {
  font-family : Catatan Perjalanan;
  font-size : 26px;
  color : #FDFEFF;
  color : rgb(253, 254, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 8%;
}
.dlputolblueimg {
    position:absolute;
    left: 20%;
    width: 14.5%;
    bottom: 21.5%;
}

img.dlputo1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.tomainmenu {
  font-family : Catatan Perjalanan;
  font-size : 26px;
  color : #FDFEFF;
  color : rgb(253, 254, 255);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8%;
  left: 10%;
}
.greenboardflat1img {
    position:absolute;
    width: 55%;
    height: auto;
    left: 22.5%;
    top: 2%;
}

img.greenboardflat1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.cateringmenubannerimg {
    position:absolute;
    top: 12%;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    left: 30%;
}

img.cateringmenubanner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.printiconwhiteimg {
    position:absolute;
    right: 7%;
    width: 5.2%;
    top: 7%;
}

img.piwhite {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.bbcatlputoimg {
    position:absolute;
    left: 7%;
    width: 5%;
    top: 7%;
}

img.bbcatlputo {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.mmcat {
    font-family : Catatan Perjalanan;
  font-size : 16px;
  color : #0700D0;
  color : rgb(7, 0, 208);
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.25%;
  top: 14%;
}
```

Comment: a **single page** website **with 2 pages** ?

Comment: @baao beat me to it. sounds a bit of an odd project, to say the list.

Comment: @user74843 can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: needs more information on what you expect the code to do

Answer (score 2):

Technically these aren't "pages," they are elements that take up 100% `height`/`width`. The problem is that your 100% `height` and `width` rules are relative to the `html` and `body` tags which do not currently have a defined height, so the "pages" are rendering with a height of `0`.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, adding this CSS should resolve it:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Additionally, in your CSS you have two different body classes defined. An HTML document can only have one set of `html` tags and one set of `body` tags, instead you should be assigning the "page" IDs/classes to two separate divs like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="pge1" class="cateringpage">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pge2" class="cateringmenupage">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```